# Using inet_pton() to get unsigned int representation of IPv4 address

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to convert an IPv4 address from `std::string` to it's `unsigned int` representation (according to [this](http://www.bennadel.com/resources/uploads/ip_to_number_bit_wise_conversion.gif)) in C++ (Windows)

I managed to do that with the following code:

```
void strIPtoUnsignedIntIP(string ipStr){
    struct sockaddr_in ip4addr;

    ip4addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipStr.c_str(), &ip4addr.sin_addr);

    unsigned int resIp = (ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 << 24) + 
                         (ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 << 16) + 
                          (ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 << 8) + 
                                  ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4;
    cout << resIp << endl;

}
```

I am getting the right values, but, the following line is not so elegant:

```
unsigned int resIp = (ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 << 24) +
                     (ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 << 16) +
                      (ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 << 8) + 
                              ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b4;
```

I was hoping that instead of using `S_un_b` field of `sin_addr` and then perform the calculation, I could simply take the `S_addr` field. Unfortunately, I am getting different values.

For example, for the string "192.168.1.1":

- When performing the calculation with `S_un_b`, I am getting the result
  3232235777 (which is the correct value)
- When simply taking the value in `S_addr`, I am getting the result
  16885952.

My questions are:

1. why is there a difference?
2. Can I utilize S_addr to get the desired value?

Comment: `S_addr` is in host order (little-endian). Your calculation produces network order (big endian). `htonl(S_addr)` would produce the same value. Observe that 3232235777==0xC0A80101, while 16885952==0x0101A8C0 - the relationship should be obvious now.

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik! htonl is what I was missing, works great now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [MSDN doc for `in_addr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922011.aspx):

```
struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
    struct { u_short s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
};
```

So what you want is just the `u_long` member, in network order (since you want `s_b1` to be the highest order byte):

```
unsigned int resIp = htonl(ip4addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
```

Comment: Possibly with a call to `ntohl`.